# Javascript - Why isNaN(1 + null) returns false?

Tags: javascript, coercion

Well,I am going through Mozilla Javascript Reference and found that..

```
isNaN(1 + null) //false
isNaN(1 + undefined) //true
```

I am not able to understand reason behind this.

Comment: `+null === 0`, `+undefined === NaN`

Comment: Have you tried printing just the value of `1 + null`? That's the base reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp, , when `null` is converted to `number`, it becomes 0. Therefore, 0 + 1 = 1, it's valid number, so `isNaN` returns `false`.

When `undefined` is converted to Number, it becomes `NaN`. `Any Number + NaN = NaN`, so `isNaN` return true.

Comment: Upvoted, but instead of w3schools, you can reference something more accurate: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-tonumber

Comment: @niki thanks for explaining this.